# Error when importing from a library in python

Tags: python

I tried importing a library and it outputs this error :
cannot import name 'nx' from 'networkx'

Is it becaues there is no 'nx' library?

Comment: Did you mean to `import networkx as nx`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you maybe be trying to import nx from networkx using the syntax:

```
from networkx import nx
```

networkx has no function nx

What you should be doing is trying to import networkx as nx:

```
import networkx as nx
```